# Search limit with Dailymotion API

Tags: dailymotion-api

I want to use Dailymotion API in order to search videos. I have read the documentation and I have not found any answer to my question.

Are there limits with the search query Dailymotion API ?

https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#video

"While some basic features are available without authentication, you will need to register yourself as a developer in order to perform more elaborate API calls, authenticate users and act on their behalf."

Is the "search videos" a basic feature ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to your question: https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#rate-limit

Basically, so far dailymotion API only enforces quotas on video upload and on field to get stream (this is very limited). There is no restriction on the search query.

You need to register to dailymotion to get an API key, which will be useful for calls that require authentication.

Comment: Thank you but actually I do have an other question : do I need an API key in order to use the Dailymotion Search Feature ? I have developped a small programm which makes me able to test and I have not used any key doing it, nevertheless I got results

Comment: Search is affected, as well: it cannot e.g. return "private" videos without the API key.

Comment: this is normal: private videos are "private", so you need to be logged with an access token from the video owner in order to access it.

Comment: I hope you add the keyword api feature